# google-maps-api-3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

My application will not recognize my KML file. The application will go to the correct location (lat/long) and zoom level, but will not recognize the KML file location. I have attempted to use two different servers to check the problem, so I believe it is the code that is the problem.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOJCBv2WGJRJ7uxOyAMehKAMiAKXkkHFU&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.88119,-93.314798),
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://webgis.uwm.edu/engelki7/KMLFiles/Richfield_Homes2.kml',{suppressInfoWindows: true});


        google.maps.event.addListener(nyLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
         var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
         showInDiv(text);
        });
      }

      function showInDiv(text) {
         var sidediv = document.getElementById('content_window');
         sidediv.innerHTML = text;
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
     <div id="map_canvas" style="width:79%; height:100%; float:left"></div>
    <div id="content_window" style="width:19%; height:100%; float:left"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your kml file does not exist.

http://webgis.uwm.edu/engelki7/KMLFiles/Richfield_Homes2.kml

Gives me: HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found

If you believe it is there (the path on the server is correct), then it is possible that the server doesn't know how to deal with kml/kmz files.  See [this portion](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server) of the documentation on kml files.